# Ajax Post to Web API succeeds but.. fails on client side when hosted on Default Web Site (IIS)

Tags: ajax, iis-7, localhost, asp.net-web-api2

I have a weird problem: I have a clientSide App (jquery) running against a WebAPI on the same domain. When I host it on IIS in my local computer, as a Root web site (Sites->MyApp) it works OK (both Get and Post). A typical API call looks like this:

```
$.get("api/GetList", null, function (data) {
        var list = data;
    })
```

but, when I host it under of "Default Web Site" in IIS, as a sub Application, a typical API call looks like this:

```
$.get("MyApp/api/GetList", null, function (data) {
        var list = data;
    })
```

All the GET calls work fine, but the POST call acts weird. I make a POST call like this:

```
$.ajax({
            url: "MyApp/api/Fields",
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            data: data,
            success: function (res) {
                var x = res;               
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                //
            }
        });
```

The web api method looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/Fields")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post() {...
```

When I execute the POST call , it gets to the server and the server method works fine, but when it returns I get an error. From here: http://localhost/MyApp/index.html  I click the submit button and get this (even though the action succeeded on server side!!):
HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
Requested URL   http://localhost:80/api/Fields?input_1=sometext

So as you can see, the route to MyApp disappeared and IIS treats the request as it was GET , although I did a POST!! and returns to the root : Default Web Site instead of returning to localhost/MyApp ..

The same code 1:1 when running on a test server on IIS with same configuration works ok without this error. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe to rephrase and shorten it a bit: I do An AJAX Post to http://localhost/MyApp/api/fields (using F5 in VS2015 I see that it reaches the right method) But I get in response: HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found Requested URL  http://localhost:80/api/Fields?input_1=123 and : the requested resource does not support http method 'get'!!!
1. It was a POST.
2. I called http://localhost/MyApp/api/fields and not http://localhost:80/api/Fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After numerous investigations with no answer from the web, I suddenly saw that the Form tag contained an action attribute!:

```
<form id="Id" name="Name" action="api/action" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
```

As soon as I removed the action attribute, it solved the extra api call.. but I also had to Prevent the default behaviour of the form. So I put the Ajax Post Api call inside the $(document).ready function like so:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
        var frm = $('#FormId');
        frm.submit(function (ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();

            //do validation etc..

            //do Ajax Post
            $.ajax({
                url: "api/Fields/",
                method: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: false,...
            });
            return false;
        });
  });
```

Don't forget to prevent the Form default behaviour!